# PyCharm unresolved reference when importing class from other file

Tags: python, pycharm

This problem has been driving me nuts. I am trying to import a class from a file in the same directory. PyCharm is giving me the "Unresolved reference" error. `MyClass` is defined in `file.py`.

[image: Unresolved reference]

I have found these questions:

- [Unresolved reference issue in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm)
- [Pycharm: "unresolved reference" error on the IDE when opening a working project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479696/pycharm-unresolved-reference-error-on-the-ide-when-opening-a-working-project)
- [PyCharm shows unresolved references error for valid code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725519/pycharm-shows-unresolved-references-error-for-valid-code)
- [Unresolved reference when importing from sibling sub-package with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969025/unresolved-reference-when-importing-from-sibling-sub-package-with)

I have the following project structure:

[image: Project structure]

I have marked src as the sources root...

I have set the "Add source roots to PYTHONPATH":

[image: Add sources option]

I have tried File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.. (I even restarted the computer).

If I try to run it, I get the following error in the console: `ImportError: cannot import name 'MyClass'`

The interpreter is a virtualenv on Python 3.4 on Ubuntu x64 14.04.

If I install and import any 3rd party packages, they work fine.

If I try `echo $PYTHONPATH` in the terminal it returns nothing (same with `env | grep PYTHONPATH`. I have the appropriate virtualenv active when I try these.

Any clues?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If `MyClass` is defined in `pack/file.py`, you need to import it as:

```
from pack.file import MyClass
```

Note that using names of Python built-in types (such as `file`) for your own modules is a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using python version 3 try this

```
from .pack import myclass
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons why this could be happening. Below are several steps that fixes the majority of those cases:

**.idea caching issue**

Some `.idea` issue causing the IDE to show error while the code still runs correctly. Solution:

1. close the project and quick PyCharm
2. delete the `.idea` folder where the project is. note that it is a hidden folder and you might not be aware of its existence in your project directory.
3. start PyCharm and recreate the project

**imports relative not to project folder**

Relative imports while code root folder is not the same as the project folder. Solution:

1. Find the folder that relative imports require in the project explorer
2. right click and mark it as "Source Root"

**Editor not marking **init**.py as Python**

Which is the most illusive of all the cases. Here, for some reason, PyCharm considers all `__init__.py` files not to be python files, and thus ignores them during code analysis. To fix this:

1. Open PyCharm settings
2. Navigate to Editor -> File Types
3. Find Python and add `__init__.py` to the list of python files or find Text and delete `__init__.py` from the list of text files

[image]

Comment: This ".idea caching issue" was the clue that I needed.  In PyCharm 2019.1 this is easily solved by selecting File >> "Invalidate Caches / Restart"

Answer (score 1):

The following steps solved my issues:

- All directories required at least a blank __init__.py file
- Mark all directories as source roots (per previous poster instructions)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are using python 3 you should add something like this:

```
from .pack import MyClass
```

It will work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I tried to import a new class, however I could successfully import functions from a file in the same directory. I still dont understand why I could not import my class but thought I would share the information for other users.

@kaylebs response worked for me. However I then added the src directory to the list of source directories, first link in @lulian 's question and could remove the '.' from my file name.

Answer (score 0):

I just delete the copied the code and delete the file and again create the same, that time it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).