# importing Object from another Class in Python is highlighted

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pycharm

in PyCharm my import highlighted in red but code works. What should I do to remove this red underline highlighting

my import looks as follow:

```
from group import Group
```

In PyCharm this line is highlighted in red but code works. 
 it says:

> Unresolved reference 'Group' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   Inspection info: This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
from .group import Group
```

see [PyCharm unresolved reference when importing class from other file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452054/pycharm-unresolved-reference-when-importing-class-from-other-file?rq=1)